# How to get model summary of a machine learning model (particularly XG boost)like the screenshot attached below?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have run Xgboost regressor on a data set and I need the model summary(for eg R squared, Kurtosis etc) similar to the screenshot attached. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hleha.png)

Comment: the screenshot seems to be a summary from `statmodels`, and XGBoost might (but probably doesn't) have some built-in summary. A summary is not a universal feature to machine learning libraries/packages

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [R square value](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score-the-coefficient-of-determination) or [performance metrics](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) using the sklearn implementation.

But the other things such as co-eff is not relevant for `Xgboost` model because it is a non-linear model. Hence you cannot assign single co-eff for each feature according to the `Xgboost` model.

There are better ways to understand the model interpretability, one of the methods which I would suggest is `[SHAP Tree explainers][2]`.

[Blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretable-machine-learning-with-xgboost-9ec80d148d27) to understand the working of shap.